# Is CSS better than tables for page layout?

Tags: html, css

I have always used tables and find them so easy. I am trying to use CSS instead and it's a nightmare. Things move all over. This is not something that happens with tables.

I know about separating design from content but, man, CSS is all over the place. I have been trying forever to get this simple template to work correctly. A header, footer, and three columns, plus a nav bar with subnav. Can anyone help me get it so that things don't just move all over. Currently, when I resize the window, even though the outer div doesn't get smaller, the header does--and it seems to be moving my right column down.

All I want is the width of all things to remain constant on window resize (whether by dragging OR by zooming out/in). Is there a straightforward way to do this (I can't find it if there is). I would think to just give each column div a width and the parent dive a width but I must be missing something.

Also, I can't seem to get the nav bar to be just a little less tall. If it gets smaller, the columns come up to high. Shouldnt the columns ALWAYS simply remain below the divs on top of it (just like a footer should always be below them)? That's what tables do? I feel like going back to tables is my best option, but I really want to get the divs to work.

**CSS FILE**

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

navigation {
    height: 62px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
    width: 470px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 210px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

#nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav ul{
    padding:0
}
#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-2px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:4px 15px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #069;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
#nav ul li a:hover{background: #6166;} /*hovercolor main menu*/
#nav ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    transition:all .5s; 
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav  ul.submenu li{
    display:block; 
}
#nav  ul.submenu li a{
    display:block;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    color: #069;
}
#nav  ul.submenu li a:hover{background: #6166;} /*hovercolor main menu*/
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    max-height: 10000px;
}   

       /************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

#pagewrap {
    width: 94%;
}
#content {
    width: 41%;
    padding: 1% 4%;
}
#middle {
    width: 41%;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    float: right;
}

#sidebar {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1% 4%;
}
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#content {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

#middle {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

header {
    height: auto;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

#content {
background: #f8f8f8;
}
#sidebar {
background: #f0efef;
}
header, #content, #middle, #sidebar {
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pagewrap, header, #content, #middle, #sidebar, footer {
border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>


<div id="pagewrap">

<header>
    <h1>xxx</h1>
</header>

<navigation>
        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</navigation>

<section id="content">
    <h2>1st Content Area</h2>
    <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout, complete with responsive images and jquery slideshow.</p>
</section>

<section id="middle">
    <h2>2nd Content Area</h2>
    xxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxxxxx xxx x x xxxx x x xxxxx
</section>

<aside id="sidebar">
    <h2>3rd Content Area</h2>
    <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
</aside>

<footer>
    <h4>Footer</h4>
        <p>Footer text</p>
    </footer>

    </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that you want the page to have a fixed width and get rid of the media queries? Then remove everything inside `@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { ... }`, remove everything inside of `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { ... }`, and everything inside of `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { ... }`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/ocqyqkbd/

Comment: And to make your navigation a little less tall, you have to adjust your margin. Add the following to your css: `#nav ul { margin: 5px 0 }`.

Comment: Just as an alternative, you could look at using something like Bootstrap instead of messing with the CSS yourself, if you're getting frustrated with it and just want your design up and going quickly.

Comment: To PhillipXT's point, using Bootstrap would be a great idea for you since you don't quite grasp CSS. And there are a ton of tutorials and help guides: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: And one more note before I go... I suggest you read up on CSS browser resets. Your page layout is going to look different from one browser to another. A good place to start is running the search `css browser reset` via Google: https://www.google.com/search?num=30&site=&source=hp&q=css+browser+reset I don't want to point you in any 1 direction because there are many techniques. But keep in mind, if you apply a browser reset technique to your stylesheet now, it will change a ton of things visually for you, such as padding, margin, list-style-type, tables, borders, anchor tags, buttons and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Float is evil. Stop using it.

More seriously, float removes the element from the flow, which makes it kind of hard to control after. Use display:inline-block instead. Fix the width or max-width of your element if needed. Much easier.

Comment: i pulled the floats and it seemed better. but still moving on zoom out. and now the menu doest work.

Comment: and now my three columns are pushed way day, like there are a whole bunch of <br> above them.

Comment: and the submenu cant be clicked on, like the middle column below it wont allow it. is there a z-order or something?

Comment: but the biggest pain is that the third column shifts down (and below the others) when zooming out.

Comment: ok, all is good except the zooming out issue. If I leave alittle room around each column, it takes longer for the zoom to be an issue.  I guess thats ok, although I like a nice tight layout without extra spaces. Not sure why it doesnt look EXACTLY the sam zoomed out... just smaller.

Comment: Don't use pixels to size elements. Think about using `em` or % given the result that you expect. Another thing to keep in mind, if there is a new line between 2 html blocks, it makes a space that will appear on the screen.

Comment: When you zoom out, the em dimensions are lowering as well as the font size (that is the point). But the % dimensions stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle of Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ocqyqkbd/1/

I guess what you're saying is that you want the page to have a fixed width no matter the size of the browser? Then get rid of the media queries... remove everything inside:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { ... }
```

Remove everything inside of:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { ... }
```

And remove everything inside of:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

To reduce the height of your navigation, you need to add to your css the following to adjust your `UL` margin:

```
#nav > ul { margin: 5px 0 }
```

Comment: As you can probably tell, I downloaded this template as a starter. Then I downloaded the navigation (since the nav in the template didnt have submenus)

Comment: Wait a minute. I remove the media queries section and it works fine. But the conditionals on it are all 980px and lower. This shouldnt impact me anyway (I am on a laptop with much higher res) I thought those sections only kick in at lower resolution screens like mobile.

Comment: scratch that. it doesnt work perfectly. it works when the window is dragged smaller (no shifting of divs) but the third column shifts down if I zoom out.

Comment: If you start a chat session, I'll help you more to help you get what you need completed.

Comment: this is so frustrating. I dont get the point of a structure where everything you do you need to worry about how all browsers interpret, things "float" all over, etc. Its like like playing whack-a-mole with your layout. Why would anyone choose this over tables? you can put classes on tables. And whenyou put them somewhere--they stay.

Comment: if I float the right column to the right it is ok--I but I thought I shouldnt use float? is there another way to force a div to the right? align right doesnt work. what about center, can you align center?

Comment: even when i change the padding in my middle column, it moves my right column. Padding is INSIDE the div. WTF?!?!